# Virtual host configuration ommited

Tags: apache-2.4

i had setup apache 2.4 on Centos to serve index.html from two virtual hosts, but regardless of port in url, apache always serves index.html from stepan.wudangtc.cz. I probably badly understood , or misconfigured something. Please advice me how to configure apache to serve also index.html from vhost pavel.wudangtc.cz. Apache listens both on port 80 and 8080.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pavel.wudangTC.cz
    ServerAlias wudangTC.cz
    DocumentRoot /aplikace/httpd/docroots/pavel

    <Directory /aplikace/httpd/docroots/pavel>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerName stepan.wudangTC.cz
   ServerAlias www.wudangTC.cz
   DocumentRoot /aplikace/httpd/docroots/stepan

   <Directory /aplikace/httpd/docroots/stepan>
           Require all granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there stay something like nginx before Apache and How You define different ports in Your http requests?

Comment: Also - You have different 'ServerAlias' - with and without www. Which URL are You using when executing HTTP request?

Comment: check "apachectl -S" to see which virtualhosts you are correctly loading. Also try with a no-cache command line client when testing, like "curl -I http://example.com:8080".